# can not create AVD for Android 2.3.3 based on Atom x86 Sysytem Image

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded the Intel Atomx86 System Image (Intel Corporation) – API Level 10 through Android SDK Manager and also installed HAXM Extra. HAXM runs properly. But when I want to create a AVD,I can not find Intel Atomx86 System Image (Intel Corporation) – API Level 10 options in target dropdown list. So I can just choose Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10 system image and choose Intel Atom (x86) for CPU/ABI,but I just got this message "[2013-02-11 10:27:28 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI x86 to copy into the AVD folder." in console.I also downloaded the I downloaded the Intel Atomx86 System Image (Intel Corporation) – API Level 17, which is for Android4.2, I can not find the specific System Image. And  I choose Android 4.2 - API Level 17 system image and choose Intel Atom (x86) for CPU/ABI,then I can create that AVD successfully.How can I create AVD for Android 2.3.3 based on Atom x86 System Image? Why things happen not just like the intel documentation says in http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager  ?
Any help? BTW,I have already used the latest ADT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After noticing the issue listed here, we fixed the system-image on the SDK repository. If you open the SDK Manager and install revision 2 of the Intel x86 System-Image for API 10, it should now work properly without having to move files around.
Despite the packaging issue, the system-image is the same.
The emulator will indicate "Android 2.3.7" (both Android 2.3.3 and 2.3.7 are API 10.)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like version 2.3.3 has misplaced the files into an internal directory. Assuming you already downloaded the x86 image, create the links in the sdk/system-images/android-10/x86 directory (I used 'ln -s' to create the symlins) . 
Here is how my directory looks like:

```
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro:x86 rafa$ pwd
/Users/rafa/Mobile/Android_adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/system-images/android-10/x86

Rafaels-MacBook-Pro:x86 rafa$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--@  1 rafa  staff   6148 Feb 18 17:07 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 rafa  staff   2491 Feb 18 04:40 ReleaseNotes.txt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rafa  staff     21 Feb 18 17:05 build.prop -> images/x86/build.prop
drwxr-xr-x   3 rafa  staff    102 Feb 18 04:40 docs
-rw-r--r--   1 rafa  staff    181 Feb 18 04:40 hardware.ini
drwxr-xr-x   3 rafa  staff    102 Feb 18 04:40 images
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rafa  staff     22 Feb 18 17:05 kernel-qemu -> images/x86/kernel-qemu
-rw-r--r--   1 rafa  staff    233 Feb 18 04:40 manifest.ini
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rafa  staff     22 Feb 18 17:05 ramdisk.img -> images/x86/ramdisk.img
drwxr-xr-x   9 rafa  staff    306 Feb 18 04:40 skins
-rw-r--r--   1 rafa  staff  13180 Feb 18 04:40 source.properties
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rafa  staff     21 Feb 18 17:06 system.img -> images/x86/system.img
lrwxr-xr-x   1 rafa  staff     23 Feb 18 17:04 userdata.img -> images/x86/userdata.img
```

Comment: Tried setting up the symlinks like you've got them, but I get: 
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
emulator: Failed to open the hax module
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Comment: Sorry,I didn't mention that I use Win7.But I also try copying and pasting the image to target directory like 4.2,none help.Can you choose the Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10 system image and choose Intel Atom (x86) for CPU/ABI by creating the symlinks?